# Getting duplicate values in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created two tables customer and customer_address_details as shown below. I have customer_id as foreign key for customer_address from customer table.

```
Customer Table:
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME | CUSTOMER_DOB |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
|           1 | PHILLIP       | 1983-01-05   |
|           2 | ROBERT        | 1981-01-05   |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+

Customer_Address Table:
+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| ADDRESS_ID | ADDRESS_STREET          | ADDRESS_CITY | ADDRESS_STATE | ADDRESS_ZIPCODE | CUSTOMER_ID |
+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
|          1 | 12345 mlk pkwy | san Antonio       | TEXAS         |           75025 |           1 |
|          2 | 12345 main st           | Austin        | TEXAS         |           75035 |           2 |
+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

When I give the following query it displays duplicate rows.

select a.customer_name,b.address_street from customer a, customer_address b where a.customer_id=1;

```
+---------------+-------------------------+
| customer_name | address_street          |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| PHILLIP       | 12345 mlk pkwy |
| PHILLIP       | 12345 main st          |
+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Could you tell me why it is giving duplicate rows even though I am asking to select address for customer_id=1?

Here is my table description

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CUSTOMER_ID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CUSTOMER_NAME | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CUSTOMER_DOB  | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ADDRESS_ID      | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ADDRESS_STREET  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ADDRESS_CITY    | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ADDRESS_STATE   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ADDRESS_ZIPCODE | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CUSTOMER_ID     | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a condition to join your tables, so you don't have every address matched with every customer.

Something like

```
select a.customer_name,b.address_street 
from customer a, customer_address b 
where a.customer_id=1 and a.customer_id=b.customer_id
```

or

```
select a.customer_name,b.address_street 
from customer a inner join customer_address b 
 on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
where a.customer_id=1
```

Comment: I updated my select statement and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Technically, it's every address matched with that one customer.. :)

Comment: @arabind, there are a few good reasons why you should always prefer the INNER JOIN syntax that EdmCoff recommends here. Broadly speaking it's harder to make errors of the type that led you to ask this question (we call these Cartesian products, where rows from one table end up joined to unrelated rows in another) when using modern join syntax

Answer (score 1):

You should join the tables:

```
select a.customer_name, b.address_street from customer a
inner join customer_address b 
on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
where a.customer_id = 1;
```

This will indicate that you want to aggregate the tables and return rows from this new relation.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables. Try this:

```
Select C.Customer_name, B.ADDRESS_STREET
 from Customer C
 join Customer_Address B on C.customer_id = B.Customer_id
 where C.Customer_id = 1
```